# Response.Redirect and back

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

My main page is Default.aspx.

When i navigate to it, in global.asax file, Session_Start method, i'm checking for some conditions, and if those are not met, i need to redirect to another page, Admin.aspx. I do that by calling

```
Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
```

From that page (after setup is done), i would like to be able to navigate back to the original page, Default.aspx, by calling

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

But that doesn't happen, Admin.aspx gets reloaded.

By examinig with Fiddler, i saw that the page Default.aspx is indeed being requested, but instead of the page content, i got "Object moved", so i'm being redirected back to Admin.aspx.

How can i get to my original location after Response.Redirect has been called? Is there an alternative to it?

P.S. Response.Redirect() is not inside try..catch block

Thank You!

EDIT: Global.asax:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...

        bool setupComplete = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SetupComplete"]);

        if (!setupComplete)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");
        }
    }
```

SetupComplete is being set to true in the admin page.

Comment: can you show more code? like the global asax or the admin behind code where the redirect is located

Comment: You say "SetupComplete" is being set to true in the admin page, but it's a local variable read from config just before being used. The error may well be here. I'd advise setting a breakpoint in Session_Start and seeing exactly what's happening.

Comment: @Andy - That's right, it is read from config. But that variable gets overwritten in config (and it does, i checked), but the next time i try to navigate to Default.aspx, i get "Object moved to here", and it navigates to the Admin page. It appears that the redirect is permanent, but i dunno how to prevent it.

Comment: How are you "overwriting that variable" (please show code)? Did you set a breakpoint in Session_Start and check setupComplete there?

Comment: @Hans Kesting - I'm using WebConfigurationManager to save SetupComplete in appSettings section of web.config file. Sorry, i'm not allowed to post the entire code. But i don't think that is the issue, because Session_Start is triggered only once per session, so even if SetupComplete was not persisted, the above code would not check for it when redirecting back to Default.aspx, because the handler has been triggered prior to that.

Comment: When you edit web.config (which is the same for all users), the website restarts which clears all Sessions. A new request would start a new session (and triggers Session_Start).

Comment: @Hans - it appears you are right about that. Sorry, i was unaware of that...